# How to get all the session id of a queue in azure service bus .Net Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

i'm making a web application which is connected to Azure  by using .Net Core 2.1.1. I encountered some problem related with service bus queue when i'm trying to get the `sessionid` of the related queue.

I found some code, but it isn't supported by the .Net Core. Here below is the code:

```
var queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(AppSettings.ServiceBusConnection, queueName);
var sessions = await queueClient.GetMessageSessionsAsync();
return sessions;
```

I also already tried this function,

```
var connString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("servicebus");
sessionClient = new SessionClient(connString, queue,ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
List<IMessageSession> sessions=new List<IMessageSession>();
while (true)
{
    var session = await sessionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync();             
    if (session == null)
        break;
    sessions.Add(session);
}
return sessions;
}
```

But it keep giving me `Timeout Exception`. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something which i tried and it worked for me, Please check the screenshot below

[image]

Here is the code i have tried

```
using System;

namespace Core.SBConsole
{
    using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
    using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    class Program
    {
        // Connection String for the namespace can be obtained from the Azure portal under the 
        // 'Shared Access policies' section.
        const string ServiceBusConnectionString = "{Connection String}";
        const string QueueName = "mvq";
        static IMessageSender messageSender;
        static ISessionClient sessionClient;
        const string SessionPrefix = "session-prefix";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            const int numberOfSessions = 5;
            const int numberOfMessagesPerSession = 3;

            messageSender = new MessageSender(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName);
            sessionClient = new SessionClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName);

            // Send messages with sessionId set
            await SendSessionMessagesAsync(numberOfSessions, numberOfMessagesPerSession);

            // Receive all Session based messages using SessionClient
            await ReceiveSessionMessagesAsync(numberOfSessions, numberOfMessagesPerSession);

            Console.WriteLine("=========================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Completed Receiving all messages... Press any key to exit");
            Console.WriteLine("=========================================================");

            Console.ReadKey();

            await messageSender.CloseAsync();
            await sessionClient.CloseAsync();
        }

        static async Task ReceiveSessionMessagesAsync(int numberOfSessions, int messagesPerSession)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("===================================================================");
            Console.WriteLine("Accepting sessions in the reverse order of sends for demo purposes");
            Console.WriteLine("===================================================================");

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSessions; i++)
            {
                int messagesReceivedPerSession = 0;

                // AcceptMessageSessionAsync(i.ToString()) as below with session id as parameter will try to get a session with that sessionId.
                // AcceptMessageSessionAsync() without any messages will try to get any available session with messages associated with that session.
                IMessageSession session = await sessionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync();// (SessionPrefix + i.ToString());

                if (session != null)
                {
                    // Messages within a session will always arrive in order.
                    Console.WriteLine("=====================================");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Received Session: {session.SessionId}");

                    while (messagesReceivedPerSession++ < messagesPerSession)
                    {
                        Message message = await session.ReceiveAsync();

                        Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

                        // Complete the message so that it is not received again.
                        // This can be done only if the queueClient is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is default).
                        await session.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine($"Received all messages for Session: {session.SessionId}");
                    Console.WriteLine("=====================================");

                    // Close the Session after receiving all messages from the session
                    await session.CloseAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        static async Task SendSessionMessagesAsync(int numberOfSessions, int messagesPerSession)
        {
            if (numberOfSessions == 0 || messagesPerSession == 0)
            {
                await Task.FromResult(false);
            }

            for (int i = numberOfSessions - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var messagesToSend = new List<Message>();
                string sessionId = SessionPrefix + i;
                for (int j = 0; j < messagesPerSession; j++)
                {
                    // Create a new message to send to the queue
                    string messageBody = "test" + j;
                    var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
                    // Assign a SessionId for the message
                    message.SessionId = sessionId;
                    messagesToSend.Add(message);

                    // Write the sessionId, body of the message to the console
                    Console.WriteLine($"Sending SessionId: {message.SessionId}, message: {messageBody}");
                }

                // Send a batch of messages corresponding to this sessionId to the queue
                await messageSender.SendAsync(messagesToSend);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("=====================================");
            Console.WriteLine($"Sent {messagesPerSession} messages each for {numberOfSessions} sessions.");
            Console.WriteLine("=====================================");
        }
    }
}
```

Things to consider before creating queue

1) Make sure service bus is not in the free or basic tier, if yes then scale it to Standadrd

2) Make sure to enable session while creating queue.

I am using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus nuget pakcage 3.4 which is latest now.If you are using some other package try to upgrade/downgrade it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the feedback. I tried your code and it works perfectly. The strange thing is when i implement it to my code, it doesn't work and only give me the Timeout Exception again. I already check the queue, and it's already enable session and also i'm using package 3.4 on Standard tier.

Comment: Try to replicate the same behaviour while creating session client object which i have given in my sample.also please accept the answer if it helped. It will others in the community who are looking for same answer.

Comment: maybe there is some reason behind this problem